# Parse Python FormData

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, forms, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I'm having difficulty finding out how to parse FormData with Python. I have base64_decoded my python string already as follows:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(base64.b64decode(event['body']))
    # dict_obj = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['body'])) #returns error
```

Now printing out the base64 decoded body prints out:

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryHFIqTxrMuAs5kep2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="username"\r\n\r\nTESTUSER\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryHFIqTxrMuAs5kep2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="regionValue"\r\n\r\nreg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryHFIqTxrMuAs5kep2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="countryValue"\r\n\r\ncountry\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryHFIqTxrMuAs5kep2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="gridValue"\r\n\r\ngrid\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryHFIqTxrMuAs5kep2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="Rate.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\nCluster Code,Pace Product Code...
```

This string contains the following information: (1) Multiple text fields (including a 'username' value), (3) two csv files in the string

How can I capture these variables from the string. I would preferably want my username as a variable and my file stored as a pandas dataframe.

Any Tips?

Comment: you might be looking for the solution explained here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218456/read-form-data-with-aws-python-lambda)

Comment: @eswar I did try and copy that code into my lambda function but I still seem to be getting an error: `[ERROR] KeyError: 'boundary'`